# Eclipse (3.6) incorrect indentation after copy paste

Tags: java, eclipse, editor

I am using Eclipse 3.6.1 Helios for java.
Whenever I copy code from any website and paste on .java of eclipse, I get that originally well indented code in only one single line.

I know this has to be related with some java editor setting in Eclipse. But couldnt figure out how to do that.

Can anybody help me please?

EDIT: I just noticed that same thing is happening when I paste code in other text editor like TextPad or NotePad. All the code from websites, which is originally nicely indented, is getting pasted in single line.

Answer (score 4):

You can use workaround: mark the code you have pasted and use Format command (default Ctrl+Shift+F). Does it fit you?

Comment: For some code it worked. But not for all. Does eclipse know if we are pasting partial code (like without completion braces etc.) does content, validity of logic of code matter for eclipse while indatation of pasted code ?

Comment: Windows-Preferences-Java-Code Style-Formatter. Here you can setup code formatter in the way you like to. Also Eclipse may not format code if it contains compile-time errors.

Comment: @user1073326: Are you sure you have copied the code correctly? If you some extra/missing braces, the code will not format properly.

Comment: In this case can we paste partial code ? Atleast every line on a separate line as in original source; pasting without indentation will also do.

Answer (score 1):

Try `Ctrl` + `All` to mark everything and then `Ctrl`+`Shift`+`f` to format it nicely. It needs though the new lines in your code.

Answer (score 1):

By <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> to use default Eclipse formatter, or you can customize your formatter by: Preferences - Java - Code Style.

Answer (score 0):

I just found this problem dissappears if I remove any line breaks before semi-colons.